# Why do both branches seem to execute?

Tags: perl, eval

I'm thoroughly confused.  Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

subtest 'huh?' => sub {
    my $i = 0;
    eval {
        $i++;
    } || do {
        $i++;
    };
    is($i, 1, "only execute one branch (i: $i)");
};

&done_testing();
```

And here's my test output (when run with ActivePerl 5.12, Mac OS X):

```
    not ok 1 - only execute one branch (i: 2)
    #   Failed test 'only execute one branch (i: 2)'
    #   at test.pl line 14.
    #          got: '2'
    #     expected: '1'
    1..1
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
not ok 1 - huh?
#   Failed test 'huh?'
#   at test.pl line 15.
1..1
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
```

What is going on here?  I expected only the first branch to run since nothing `die`s.  But it looks like both branches are executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$i++` returns the value of `$i` *before* increment. So since it's 0, then it's false. And `eval` returns the last result evaluated, which is that false value. It then goes on to try the next block (as it should).

If you want it only to take the first branch, you need to make the increment expression "increment, *then* return", like this `eval { ++$i }`.

Now, the best way to see if an `eval` failed is not to return 1 but to do the following:

1. localize `$@` ( or `$English::EVAL_ERROR` )
2. eval
3. test `$@`

   ```
   local $@;
   eval { $some_sub->(); };
   croak( "Failed in evaluate: $@" ) if $@;
   ```

Comment: Ah ... so when I use `eval` for trapping exceptions, I should always make sure it returns a true value, in case no exception was thrown inside the `eval`?

Comment: @MattFenwick, well if you are going to test the return with an `||` or an `or`, then yes. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: If you are running on a version of perl before they fixed the bug, `$@` could get cleared in a `DESTROY` block before the `if $@` statement gets a chance to run.  `eval {...; 1} or croak ...` does not suffer from that bug.

Answer (score 2):

`eval { $i ++ }` returns the same result that `$i ++` returns, namely the value that `$i` had before it was incremented.  Since you set `$i` to `0`, it return `0`, which is false, which means that the right operand of the `||` is also evaluated.

I think you're confusing the result *returned* by `eval` (which is simply the result of the contained expression) with the result of `die` within an `eval`, which is saved in `$@`.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll have to go refactor my code base to check `$@` instead of the return value of `eval`.

Comment: @briandfoy: Yes, [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)